# What is the difference between ledger accounts and non ledger accounts in hedera hashpack wellets

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashpack

Tried to connect my hashpack wallet with a hedera based NFT maeketplace and I have encountered this error.

"No available wallets - Ledger accounts are unable to be used with HashConnect. Please create a non-ledger account."

what exactly mean by a non ledger account

I am expecting to connect my hashpac wallet and perform various operations with theat nft marketplace

Answer (score 1):

I found the basic diff between the ledger and non-ledger accounts now. Though the hashpack is a non-ledger account I could not able to figure out why it is not connecting and stating the same.

A Ledger account refers to an account on the Hedera network that is associated with a Ledger hardware wallet. Ledger is a popular hardware wallet that allows you to securely store your cryptocurrency assets offline.

A non-Ledger account, on the other hand, is an account on the Hedera network that is not associated with a Ledger hardware wallet. It is typically created using a software wallet, such as the Hashpac wallet, or through a software development kit (SDK).

When you create an account on the Hedera network using a Ledger hardware wallet, the private key associated with the account is stored securely on the device. This provides an additional layer of security, as the private key cannot be easily accessed by hackers or other malicious actors. However, using a Ledger hardware wallet to manage your account can sometimes be more cumbersome than using a software wallet, as it requires you to physically connect the device to your computer and enter a PIN code to access your funds.

In contrast, a non-Ledger account is typically easier to manage, as it can be accessed using a software wallet that is installed on your computer or mobile device. While the security of a software wallet may not be as robust as a hardware wallet like Ledger, it can still be secure when proper security measures are taken.

When connecting to the Hashpac wallet, you may need to create a non-Ledger account in order to interact with the wallet, as Ledger accounts are currently not supported